# Ionic Native - File - err "code : class not found"

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am learning Ionic and following tutorials. I'm working with taking a picture with the camera then getting the image path and storing it. For this I'm using `import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';`

It's not working, I'm using a `toast` to pass the error message. The error message in my toast is:

***Error Message*** `{"code":"class not found"}`

First, I installed it via:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

Then I added to my *`app.module.ts`*:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { SetLocationPage } from '../pages/set-location/set-location';
import { PlacePage } from '../pages/place/place';
import { AddPlacePage } from '../pages/add-place/add-place';
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
import { PlacesService } from '../services/places';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    AddPlacePage,
    PlacePage,
    SetLocationPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: ''
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    AddPlacePage,
    PlacePage,
    SetLocationPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    PlacesService,
    Geolocation,
    Camera,
    File
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then here's my code to essentially save the camera image:

*`add-place.ts`* *look at method onTakePhoto()*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalController, LoadingController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { File, Entry, FileError } from '@ionic-native/file';

import { SetLocationPage } from '../set-location/set-location';
import { Location } from '../../models/location';
import { PlacesService } from '../../services/places';

declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-place',
  templateUrl: 'add-place.html',
})
export class AddPlacePage {
  location: Location = {
    lat: 40.7624324,
    lng: -73.9759827
  };
  locationIsSet = false;
  imageUrl = '';

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
              private toastCtrl: ToastController,
              private placesService: PlacesService,
              private geolocation: Geolocation,
              private camera: Camera,
              private file: File) {}

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.placesService.addPlace(form.value.title, form.value.description, this.location, this.imageUrl);
    form.reset();
    this.location = {
      lat: 40.7624324,
      lng: -73.9759827
    };
    this.imageUrl = '';
    this.locationIsSet = false;
  }

  onOpenMap() {
    const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(SetLocationPage, {location: this.location, isSet: this.locationIsSet});
    modal.present();
    modal.onDidDismiss(
      data => {
        if (data) {
          this.location = data.location;
          this.locationIsSet = true;
        }
      }
    );
  }

  onLocate() {
    const loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Getting your Location...'
    });
    loader.present();
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
      .then(
        location => {
          loader.dismiss();
          this.location.lat = location.coords.latitude;
          this.location.lng = location.coords.longitude;
          this.locationIsSet = true;
        }
      )
      .catch(
        error => {
          loader.dismiss();
          const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: 'Could not get location, please pick it manually!',
            duration: 2500
          });
          toast.present();
        }
      );
  }

  onTakePhoto() {
    this.camera.getPicture({
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      correctOrientation: true
    })
    .then(
      imageData => {
        const currentName = imageData.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        const path = imageData.replace(/[^\/]*$/, '');
        this.file.moveFile(path, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, currentName)
          .then(
            (data: Entry) => {
              this.imageUrl = data.nativeURL;
              this.camera.cleanup();
              // this.file.removeFile(path, currentName);
            }
          )
          .catch(
            (err: FileError) => {
              this.imageUrl = '';
              const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: String(JSON.stringify(err)), //'Could not save the image. Please try again.',
                duration: 2500
              });
              toast.present();
              this.camera.cleanup();
            }
          );
        this.imageUrl = imageData;
      }
    )
    .catch(
      err => {
        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Could not take the image. Please try again.',
          duration: 2500
        });
        toast.present();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Just to add, I tested the app also on an iOS device, and the function works. But on an android app, the function does not work. So it must be something to do with Android. Any ideas greatly appreciated.